# Form Loading Itself

Tags: forms, 8

I want to load a form with values from a DB using a date so that the user can edit the data later - however, it doesn't input the data into the fields beyond the initial load. I've created a very basic code to demonstrate my problem: I just think I'm not understanding the appropriate solution to this issue.

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if ($form_state->hasValue('date')) {
      $date = $form_state->get('date');
      $result = 'Date Set';
    } else {
      $form_state->setValue('date', REQUEST_TIME);
      $result = 'Date Not Set';
    }

    $form['ajax_wrapper'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => [
        'id' => 'ajax_wrapper',
      ],
    ];

    $form['ajax_wrapper']['date'] = [
      '#type' => 'date',
      '#title' => $this->t('Date'),
    ];

    $form['ajax_wrapper']['submit_button'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Load',
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxFormCallback'],
      ],
    ];

    $form['ajax_wrapper']['result'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Result'),
      '#default_value' => $result,
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    dd('submit');
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  public function ajaxFormCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    dd('callback');
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#ajax_wrapper', $form));
    return $response;
  }
```

Comment: The ajax callback should return the part of the form array that was updated

Comment: @Eyal That doesn't seem to change anything for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is the wrong way to go about it, but I managed to get what I wanted to happen to happen. It turns out the values being displayed on the form aren't what is in $form_state->getValue, but $form_state->getUserInput. This will successfully load the value 'Date Set' into the result box when it is submitted.

```
if ($form_state->hasValue('date')) {
  $user_input = $form_state->getUserInput();
  $userInput['result'] = 'Date Set';
  $form_state->setUserInput();
} else {
  $form_state->setValue('date', REQUEST_TIME);
  $result = 'Date Not Set';
}
```

Comment: Your code had mistakes:

if ($form_state->hasValue('date')) {
  $user_input = $form_state->getUserInput();
  $user_Input['result'] = 'Date Set';
  $form_state->setUserInput($user_Input);
} else {
  $form_state->setValue('date', REQUEST_TIME);
  $result = 'Date Not Set';
}

Comment: `setUserInput` isn't hungry. Why?

Answer (score 1):

When you are working with ajax you have to store everything that has to be preserved in the $form_state's storage.

So in your example it would be:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $date = REQUEST_TIME;
    if ($form_state->has('date')) {
      $date = $form_state->get('date');
    } else {
      $form_state->set('date', $date);
    }

    // ...

    $form['ajax_wrapper']['date'] = [
      '#type' => 'date',
      '#title' => $this->t('Date'),
      '#default_value' => $date
    ];

    // ...

    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $date = $form_state->getValue('date');
    $form_state->set('date', $date);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }
```

Comment: I've updated my code to match the changes you offered, but I still can't get it to function correctly - the result textfield does not change.

Comment: Use #prefix and #suffix for ajax wrapper since ajax will replace the whole structure that you are returning with your ajax submit handler instead of container with attribute.

Comment: Switching to prefix/suffix instead of creating my container as it's own array item doesn't seem to change the result.